# TFS 2010 with Project Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, project-server, ms-project-server-2010

I've just tried out TFS 2010 today, along with Project 2010 and VS 2010. Only Later realized that without Sharepoint, TFS is only configured as Basic. This reduces it's functionality as oppose to what I've seen during VS2010 product launch. Sadly I can't find any alternative but to get a trial copy of Sharepoint to see if it serve my purpose. Well, apparently Sharepoint only comes with x64 edition. I'm not formatting any machine to x64 just to give this a try. So, after some reading up, I found that Project Server is actually based on Sharepoint. Now I wonder is whether TFS can be configure to connect to Project Server?

If it's possible, would the setting be much different that Sharepoint's?

And what am I missing from this setup as oppose to Sharepoint's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Sharepoint != Sharepoint.  I think that Project Server is just a subset of Sharepoint functionality.  Also, basing Project on Sharepoint allows for some really tight integration into your portal.  To answer your question, I don't think you still will get your fully featured TFS without Sharepoint Proper.

FYI - Sharepoint 2007 (or 3.0 or whatever it is) is not x64 only, but will run on x86.  TFS 2010 will go full feature on 2007

[Sharepoint 2007 Trial](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2e6e5a9c-ebf6-4f7f-8467-f4de6bd6b831&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2):

To answer what you are missing:

- Reports
- Project Portal
- TFS Web Access

That's about it.  You still get 90% of the features with your current deployment without SharePoint.  Tommy is right about MOSS 2007, it comes in 32-bit and will give you all features.  Project Server runs on top of SharePoint as a shared service provider.  Traditionally MS releases a power toy to integrate TFS with Project Server.  They said they would go over this at TechEd, which just happened about a week ago.

Also, I suspect the integration with Project Server 2010 will be better, but then you will have to run SharePoint 2010 :(

In my opinion, TFS has enough to run most projects by itself and you can use the client version of MS Project for critical path anaylsis, etc.

Comment: So document hosting will be part of the Project Portal? What I wanted is to be able to attach document like UML along with the project

Comment: @faulty: you don't need SharePoint to do that. You can attach documents to work items, or include the documents in source control directly.

Comment: You can also use the UML diagramming available natively in VS 2010 Ultimate.  They don't support *all* UML diagrams, but many of the most popular.  You also have some assistance in maintaining those diagrams over time in VS 2010 where you don't in many other tools.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not formatting any machine to x64
> just to give this a try.

Why not use VMWare Server, Hyper-V, Virtual Box or some other virtualization software to run the pre-made demo/trial/lab VHD's - no formatting, no installation, no setup, more hair.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/briankel/now-available-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate-virtual-machines-with-sample-data-and-hands-on-labs)

Comment: I installed Sharepoint 2010 on an Q9450 w/ 8GB RAM Server 2008 R2 and it was dogging that machine unlike anything I have ever seen.  Not knocking SP 2010, but I can't imagine the slowness that it would have running virtualized w/o some serious hardware.

Comment: Its funny - you get very mixed reports. I've got 2010 running under VMWare server with only 3GB and dual core E8400 (host machine runs Win 7 with lots of stuff inc VS2008/2010) and its runs acceptably. Not as good as WSS3 but good enough for dev. There must be something thats critical above the mem issues.

Comment: I run VM's all the time and generally the problem (after memory, of which you have plenty) is disk.  Don't put your virtual disks on the same spindles or go grab a SSD drive (or 2).  Simple grabbing a cheap USB 2 or esata drive and moving the virtual disks to different drives will do wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Sharepoint Services for Windows 2003 & Windows 2008:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb400747.aspx

For Windows Server 2008 sp2 and Windows Server R2, use SharePoint Foundation 2010:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en

Both are free.